# After converting "select" dropdown to list drowndown, div show/hide stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Rather than the "Select" type of dropdown I want a ul.  But, after converting to ul, my javascript isn't firing and I can't figure out why.  It works great as a Select...am I missing something?

Here is the original Select (working)

```
<div class="container">
    <select id="selector1" name="divshowhide">
      <option selected disabled value="null">Sort By:</option>
      <option value="#Online-holder">Online Now</option>
      <option value="#Lowest-holder">Lowest Price First</option>
      <option value="#Best-holder">Best Rating First</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the ul version: (not working)

```
<li><a href="#">Sort</a>
    <ul class="dropdown" id="selector1">
        <li><a href="#" value="Online-holder">Online Now</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Lowest-holder">Lowest Price First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Alpha-holder">Alpha</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Online-holder').show();
  $('#Online-link').click(function() {
    $('#Online').toggle(400);
    return false;
  });


  $('#Lowest-holder').hide();
  $('#Lowest-link').click(function() {
    $('#Lowest').toggle(400);
    return false;
  });


  $('#Alpha-holder').hide();
  $('#Alpha-link').click(function() {
    $('#Alpha').toggle(400);
    return false;
  });

});

jQuery("#selector1").change(function(){
    var div = jQuery(this).val();
    $('.holder').hide(200);
    jQuery(div).show(200);
});
</script>
```

Help!  Thank you!

Comment: An UL doesn't have a `change` event, it generally doesn't change, unless you change it programatically. You can't just replace a select with an UL and expect it to work the same way, one is an interactive element that accepts user actions, the other is just a static unordered list.

Comment: Well, that makes sense :)  No wonder I'm pulling my hair out.  I'll find another way..thank you - is there another way I can do this without select?  It belongs in my top nav and so far without using ul I cannot format it to fit the rest of the menu items.

Comment: You can use an UL as a select menu, but it takes a lot more work, and you'd have to programatically create all the functionality, that's why there are pre-made libraries that do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since your element became a clickable one rather than a selectable one, you can change your `change` function to a `click` function like this:

```
jQuery("#selector1 li").click(function(){
  var div = jQuery("a", this).attr("value");
  $('.holder').hide(200);
  jQuery(div).show(200);
});
```

Comment: Thank you..it's trying but rather than showing the div related to the link, it's hiding all divs.